# How to find out two usb devices are on the same hub

Tags: linux, usb, usb-device, ttyusb

I have a microcontroller board which has a USB hub to which several CP2108 USB to serial modules are connected and one PIC Microcontroller is connected.

The USB hub is connected to Laptop USB Port..

The CP2108 devices are assigned /dev/ttyUSB0, /dev/ttyUSB1 ID's, whereas the PIC Microcontroller is assigned a /dev/usb/abc.

If I connect another USB device to Laptop USB Port, it will get /dev/ttyUSB2

I want to verify whether /dev/ttyUSB and /dev/usb/abc are on the same hub and not on different one..

Is there any way to find out.. I tried to look into sysfs , but I am unable to find out the difference

Answer (score 2):

1. Try `lsusb -t`, which shows a tree-like view of usb buses, ports,
   and devices.

   (Stolen from [Rolf's answer to *Tool to list USB devices as tree in
   shell?*](https://askubuntu.com/a/781913/561230))
2. For a GUI, try [`usbview`](https://codeyarns.com/2015/07/30/usbview-on-linux/).